# updating variables of all activities in android application

Tags: android

I am working on an android application in which I need to update variables from different activities any time. I have tried using service but it will not serve my purpose for 100 of screens and 5000 variables updating all the time.

Comment: Why variables and why not SQLite if there are 5000 variabels?

Comment: I think it depends on the requirement, so as you haven't mentioned why you want to update variable, it won't be understand by anyone.

Comment: you need to update the status of variables or the value of those variables?

Comment: I agree with @vini. Why would you need to update variables in an activity that might not be active [on stack]? May be posting your requirement would help.

Comment: I am writing code for automating R O plant in which there are many processes running any moment value of any variable may change like when filtering pressure may increase and need to shutdown motors and give message to server also at the same time means within that second. I have sensors on R O Plant which gives some value when  sensors values reaches to some amount it should update multiple screens in my application